# offsetwidth for Chrome returns different values

Tags: google-chrome, offsetwidth

[code](https://jsfiddle.net/9e5fcpf4/) to get

```
inner.offsetWidth
```

the result for me is 2, but some people got 1. Even when we have the same Chrome version. In IE, it returns 1.

btw, my result is

offsetWidth: 2
version: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the zoom level.

Comment: @JoshLee yes. but this did not happen in some old Chrome.